# Modular arithmetic r = c (mod a), s = c (mod b), find (mod a)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Assume that $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ and that $a | b$. Let $r \equiv c \pmod a$ and $s \equiv c
\pmod b$. What is $s \pmod a$?

So I know the following: 
$r \equiv c \mod a$
$s \equiv c\mod b$

Which implies by rule $a \equiv b \pmod m$ is the same as $b \equiv a \pmod m$,
$c \equiv r \pmod a$
$c \equiv s \pmod b$

Which implies that 
$r \pmod a = s \pmod b$

However after that I do not know how to prove $s \pmod a$ from here. Am I overlooking a modular arithmetic rule or should I solve it differently?

Comment: What's $m$?. Another thing, just note that $a|b$ and $b|s-c$, so $a|s-c$.

Comment: m in line 5 is just a general formulation of a rule

Comment: **Hint** $  $ Congruences always *persist* modulo a factor of the modulus , i.e.  $$ a\mid b,\,\ r\equiv c\!\!\!\pmod b\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ r\equiv c\!\!\!\pmod a\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ \ a\mid b\mid r\!-\!c\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid r\!-\!c $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this may help you. Since $a|b$ and $b|s-c$ we get $a|s-c$, i.e., $s\equiv c \pmod a$, but $c\equiv r \pmod a$. So by transitivity we deduce that $s\equiv r\pmod a$.

Comment: But since I wanted to find s (mod a) I find it is c right?

Comment: It's $c$ or $r$. Both work because $c\equiv r\pmod a$.